# Listener method (interface in Service) in my Activity doesn't want to display a simple message

Tags: android, service, interface, listener

Good day to you all. I'm experiencing quite an issue right now with my simple Android application.

The 2 main elements I have are a **bound Service** and a main **Activity**. I want the Activity to display (through TextViews) the fact that the Service found something.
To do so, I declare a Listener interface within the Service, handle a list of listeners registered to him and notify the listeners with a specific method.

**MyService**

```
    void notifyNewElement(){
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.handleNewElement(this);
        }
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void handleNewElement(MyService sender);
    }

    private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

    public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listeners.remove(listener);
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        registerListener();
                    }
                });
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        unresgisterListener();
                    }
                });

    void registerListener(){
        tService.addListener(this);
    }

    void unresgisterListener(){
        tService.removeListener(this);
    }

    public void handleNewElement(MyService sender) {
        Log.d("NEW_ELEM","new element found");
        message_box.setText("new element found");
    }
```

I ofcourse recovered the TextViews and such in the Activity, I don't have to show the code here as I know everything's fine on that side.
As you can see in the last method, the **Log.d() works fine**, the method is really triggered. But when I want to **update the TextView**, the Activity **can't do it** PLUS **the service stops** doing his calculations.
As funny as it could be, if I unregister the listener and register it again (through the 2 buttons you can see in the Activity), the Service calculations don't get stopped anymore when triggering handleNewElement, yet the TextView is still not updated (it just doesn't block anymore).

I used exactly the same setup in another application and it worked like a charm :/

If you guys have any idea of what could be the cause of all that trouble, it'd be wonderful for you to share it !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately no. All I can see is that I do have some Log.d in my Service (within its calculus) and they stop whenever the handle method is triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void handleNewElement(MyService sender) {
    Log.d("NEW_ELEM","new element found");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            message_box.setText("new element found");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: wow great, thanks for the fast and concise answer ! I knew that was something around not updating the right thread, but had no idea how to do it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hope you have understood the real issue. There are multiple ways of doing it, and only one is shown above. You can look at [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class as well as  [`View.post`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

Comment: Yeah I do understand the issue, yet I don't get why it worked flawlessly on my other app (could it be because the other one is for Honeycomb and this one for Gingerbread ?)