# Android AlertDialog doesn't get displayed while calling from one method but it gets displayed from another method in the same activity. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, display

I am in an activity and I am trying to display an alert dialog. The code is this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("xx");
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                built.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.giveup, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                built.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        built = builder.create();
        built.show();
```

The thing is, the same code is called in two different places in the activity  and one works while the other doesn't! I don't understand because they are literally the same...

There are questions like this in this site and I tried most of them. I changed the `this` in the parameter to the activity name, I set a position, I put show() method, etc... I do not know how to proceed

And I put breakpoints in both of the places. The working one goes smoothly. But when it does not get displayed, the breakpoint crashes at 'builder.create()'. It doesn't go further than this (it doesnt see the next breakpoint which is built.show). It says "frames are not available"

Comment: Could you edit and put the codes which are calling the alert? There's nothing wrong with the alert showing code itself.

Comment: Well, the not working one is called in an emitter (listener) could it be because of that? (Sorry I am not allowed to share more of the code)

Comment: And the working one is called in "onContextItemSelected"

Comment: Yes, maybe your listener are not being called for whatever reason. You should look more closely there.

Comment: No the listener is called, because the method which is trying to display the alertdialog is entered. After the create() method, the things go down

Comment: @TiagoLoureiro I found my mistake.. I was not updating the UI thread. I got it now. Thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Just putting it here in case someone needs it. I found it from here: [Listener method (interface in Service) in my Activity doesn't want to display a simple message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306221/listener-method-interface-in-service-in-my-activity-doesnt-want-to-display-a)

The problem was that, I was calling the "not-working" one from an emitter.listener, thus it was not working on the correct thread. We need this to work on UI thread. When I added this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
           showAlertDialog();
        }
    });
```

It worked!